# I use CountDownTimer to achieve 5 seconds countdown,but the time is wrong,why?

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I use CountDownTimer to achieve 5 seconds countdown,the following is my code:

```
public class CountDownTimerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button button;
MyCountTimer timer;
boolean isTick = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_count_down_timer);

    timer = new MyCountTimer(5*1000,1000);
    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.countdown);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (!isTick){
                timer.start();
                isTick = !isTick;
            }
        }
    });
}

class MyCountTimer extends CountDownTimer{

    public MyCountTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long l) {
        button.setText(l/1000+"秒");
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        button.setText("Sms Verification Code");
        isTick = false;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    timer.cancel();
    isTick = false;
}
```

}

But I find a strange phenomenon,for example I first click the button,it will show 4,3,2,1 and sometimes I again click the button,it maybe 5,3,2,1 or 5,4,2,1.I don't know the reason,I expected result is 5,4,3,2,1. who can help me?

Comment: Why do you set isTick= !isTick if it's already false? Maybe I'm being picky but that seems strange. Also the fact you are using two different way to set isTick false doesn't make it the easiest to read.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is with

```
button.setText(l/1000+"秒");
```

Change it to

```
int second = Math.round(l/1000f);
button.setText(second +"秒");
```

If there is some delay or tick will run too early you will get `l = 3999` and you divide it to 1000 you will get 3. Thats why you have strange results.

Comment: I try that just like you said,but the result become 5,4,3,2 and the 1 is missing

Answer (score 0):

I have used **Handler** instead of using **CountDownTimer** to achieve the countdown. You can try like this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView label;
    private Handler mTimerHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        label = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label);

        findViewById(R.id.btnStartTimer).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mTimerHandler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
                mTimerHandler.postDelayed(new Timer(MainActivity.this, 5), 1000);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (mTimerHandler != null) {
            mTimerHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
            mTimerHandler = null;
        }
    }

    private static class Timer implements Runnable {

        int count = 1;
        int max;

        WeakReference<MainActivity> ui;

        Timer(@NonNull MainActivity activity, int max) {
            this.ui = new WeakReference<>(activity);
            this.max = max;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (count <= max) {
                ui.get().label.setText(String.format("%s sec", count++));
                ui.get().mTimerHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            } else {
                ui.get().label.setText("Sms verification completed.");
                ui.get().mTimerHandler.removeCallbacks(this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, I try ,it's ok. But I would like to know the way of CountDownTimer why not, where is the problem?

Comment: I try,and it make 5,4,3,2 and 1 is missing,but I find a good idea,if you  want 5 second Countdown , you should `new CountDownTimer(5200,1000)`,that's ok ,and it will show 5,4,3,2,1

Comment: **CountDownTimer** is not reliable, with **Handler** you can get a clear implementation and does not have to depend on approximate solution like you are doing by adding 200.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my question,because the CountDownTimer is inaccurate,it tolerance scope is 1-10ms, so if you want to 5s CountDown,you can add 200ms to the millisInFuture. for example:

```
timer = new MyCountTimer(5200,1000);

 @Override
 public void onTick(long l) {
     button.setText(l/1000+"second");
 }
```

it will show 5,4,3,2,1